# Rails: No route matches even when action and controller are defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this error: 
No route matches {:action=>"new_goal", :method=>"get", :controller=>"home"}

```
<%= form_tag(:action =>"new_goal", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= select_tag "deadline-type", "<option>before I turn</option><option>before</option>".html_safe%>   
  <%= submit_tag "Let's do this!", :name => nil, :class => "radius black button" %>      
<% end %>
```

I've the home controller specified as a resources in routes.rb

```
resources :home, :controller => "home"
```

**Update: It works when I change it to this, but I still don't understand why the previous approach didn't work -**

```
<%= form_tag("/new_goal", :method => "get") do %>
```

And added this to routes:

```
match '/new_goal', :controller => 'home', :action => 'new_goal'
```

Comment: try `rake routes` at the command line to see all the routes, which controllers they are associated with, what is expected to be in their paths, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no action new_goal in your routes, take into account that resources only define index, show create, update and delete. If you are using rails 3

```
resources :home, :controller => "home" do
  get :new_goal
end
```

In case of rails 2

```
resources :home, :controller => "home", :member => { :new_goal =>  :get}
```

Comment: did you restarted the application? Change :member for :collection in the second example

Comment: Yep, I restarted it each time after I tried the 3 options you've suggested (incd. :collection), but I still see the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to `form_tag` are ambiguous, because you don't close the Hash.

```
<%= form_tag({ :action =>"new_goal" }, :method => "get") do %>
```

Rails was trying to use `method` as a paramater for URL lookup.

Comment: That changed the error to this: No route matches {:action=>"new_goal", :controller=>"home"}

Comment: Where is that route defined?  You'll probably need to combine my answer with @Fernando's.  Though does `#new_goal` really reside inside `HomeController`, not inside something like `GoalsController`?

Comment: #new_goal is inside the HomeController. I changed it to <%= form_tag("/new_goal", :method => "get") do %> and added this to routes: match '/new_goal', :controller => 'home', :action => 'new_goal'. This works

Comment: Using both my solution *and* @Fernando's solution should work, without having to hard-code the path.